# How to create finite state transducers by compiling a grammar?

Tags: nlp, grammar, bnf, finite-automata, state-machine

I'm using the OpenFST library and I'd like to develop finite state transducers (FSTs) at a higher level by describing grammar using Backus Naur Form (BNF).

Has anyone been able to compile BNF grammars into an OpenFST-consumable form?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the [Thrax](http://openfst.cs.nyu.edu/twiki/bin/view/GRM/Thrax) toolkit (associated with [OpenGRM](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/GRM/NGramLibrary), but for use with hand-written grammars, rather than n-gram counting). You might find the forum link from the Thrax wiki page helpful as you get started.